# Why does this ask for three inputs when there are only two scanf calls?

Tags: c, scanf

The following code has two `scanf` calls, but when I run it, it asks for three inputs. I assume the problem comes from `\n`, but why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *s,*t;
  s=malloc(1024);t=malloc(1024);
  scanf("%s\n",s);
  scanf("%s\n",s);
  if(s==t)
  {
    printf("Same!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Different\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: "it ask for 3 inputs?" dues to `"\n"`.  `scanf("%s\n",s);` --> `scanf("%s",s);`.  Even better, research and use `fgets()`.

Comment: Where is it getting 3 inputs? BW string comparison requires `strcmp`

Comment: `s==t` compare pointer addresses. Will not be the same.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf

Comment: oh you are right didn't notice that , i was just following cs50 exercise course

Comment: @Ed Heal if you run the code it's will ask you to enter 3 inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume the problem comes from \n, but why?

You are correct that this is the problem.

According to the documentation of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), the `\n` character in the format string will cause `scanf` to continue reading whitespace characters, until it encounters a non-whitespace character. This means that after you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, `scanf` will wait for you to enter a non-whitespace character, but it will only receive this character after you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again (assuming that your operating system sends input one line at a time to your program). This is most likely not what you want.

If you want to read a single line of input, I recommend that you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Note that the `%s` `scanf` format specifier will only read a single word of input, whereas `fgets` will read an entire line of input.

Comment: thanks for help, btw you can take the entire line with scanf by using %[^\n] instead of %s